# I have a USB audio interface with multiple inputs and am looking for a way to force one input to left and another to right

Tags: audio, microphone, sound-volume

I can do this in a DAW like Ableton Live by selecting individual inputs and panning as needed, one track per input and combine. But, I do not want to run a giant DAW just to have stereo sound and am looking for just a system-level software mixer that is more granular.

Windows has this in its native mixer and but Mac just combines both in dual-mono as one device with no panning control. Blackhole also cannot do this and it's not clear if any of the Rogue Amoeba software can as most of their stuff seems focused on effects and complex routing between apps.

Comment: On phone so search is limited. Check my profile & search Rogue Amoeba. Audio Hijack can do this. Loop back maybe but I’m less familiar with that.

Comment: I checked the trial of Audio Hijack and (I think) it kind of works but introduces some distortion and what sounds like nearly a full second of latency (normally I see about 5ms in my DAW). Also just noticed the price, which is ... a bit much for the functionality I'm looking for. Maybe I can figure out how to add it to blackhole given time.

Comment: I've never known anything by Rogue Amoeba introduce any artefacting or latency. (Yeah, the price is high for a one-trick pony) Wish you luck with Blackhole - I'm afraid it's not something I've ever used.

Comment: Actually, I found my interface (MOTU M4) has a semi-hidden feature where it will treat input 1 as L and 2 as R. Holding down either of the MON buttons for 3 seconds and it goes into stereo mode (a dot appears between the 1 and 2 in the Input monitoring section). I guess the question still stands for anyone without this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely get on board the Rogue Amoeba train. They offer free demo versions so you can be sure they work before purchasing a license. Their software has very high value IMO.

- https://www.rogueamoeba.com/

Should you find any distortion in their product, their support and engineering are top notch.

Comment: These kind of products are great for what they do, but definitely too heavyweight, non-performant, and too costly for the specific issue at-hand.

Comment: Understood @JGurtz - they do so much, sometimes it’s hard to justify it for occasional use. However, if you need this - their tools will do precisely what you need.